Adjusting Orthographic Projection of Sphere in TikZ for Precise Boundary Intersection
Credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726538/319072

I am trying to draw an orthographic projection of a sphere in tikz, where only the parts facing the viewer are visible.
This can be approximated by taking the dot product (from How can I make a conditional which tests whether a point in 3d is in front of, or behind a plane?) of the start point of a line segment on the sphere, and the camera vector from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729510/319072.
However, even with high iterations (which slow down the compilation significantly), it is still visible that they either do not touch the sphere's boundary, or they go past it.
Is there a way to make them intersect the boundary perfectly at lower iterations?
The goal is to fix an animation where this problem is pronounced.
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

% azimuth and elevation
\pgfmathsetmacro{\elevation}{60}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\azimuth}{130}

% parametric sphere formula
\newcommand{\sphereX}[2]{cos(#1)*cos(#2)}
\newcommand{\sphereY}[2]{cos(#1)*sin(#2)}
\newcommand{\sphereZ}[2]{sin(#1)}

% Credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729510/319072
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CameraX}{sin(\azimuth)*cos(\elevation)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CameraY}{-cos(\azimuth)*cos(\elevation)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CameraZ}{sin(\elevation)}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{90-\elevation}{\azimuth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{50}{50}{50}

% outer circle
\draw[red, ultra thin, tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0) circle[radius=1];

% latitudinal lines
\foreach \latitude in {0,30,...,330}{

    % rotation transformation for start point
    \tdplottransformrotmain
    {\sphereX{0}{\latitude}}
    {\sphereY{0}{\latitude}}
    {\sphereZ{0}{\latitude}}

    % initial start points
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastix}{\tdplotresx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastiy}{\tdplotresy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastiz}{\tdplotresz}
    
    \foreach \longitude [
    evaluate=\longitude as \Vx using {\sphereX{\longitude}{\latitude}}
    ,evaluate=\longitude as \Vy using {\sphereY{\longitude}{\latitude}}
    ,evaluate=\longitude as \Vz using {\sphereZ{\longitude}{\latitude}}
    ,remember=\tdplotresx as \lastx (initially \lastix)
    ,remember=\tdplotresy as \lasty (initially \lastiy) 
    ,remember=\tdplotresz as \lastz (initially \lastiz) 
    ] in {30,60,...,360}{

        % rotation transformation for intermediate points
        \tdplottransformrotmain{\Vx}{\Vy}{\Vz}

        % calculate dot product
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentDotProduct}
        {\lastx*\CameraX + \lasty*\CameraY + \lastz*\CameraZ}
    
        % Check if the dot product is positive
        \pgfmathparse{\currentDotProduct>0}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \draw[ultra thin] (\lastx,\lasty,\lastz) -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz);
        \fi
    }
}

% latitudinal lines
\foreach \longitude in {0,30,...,330}{

    % rotation transformation for start point
    \tdplottransformrotmain
    {\sphereX{\longitude}{0}}
    {\sphereY{\longitude}{0}}
    {\sphereZ{\longitude}{0}}

    % initial start points
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastix}{\tdplotresx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastiy}{\tdplotresy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastiz}{\tdplotresz}
    
    \foreach \latitude [
    evaluate=\latitude as \Vx using {\sphereX{\longitude}{\latitude}}
    ,evaluate=\latitude as \Vy using {\sphereY{\longitude}{\latitude}}
    ,evaluate=\latitude as \Vz using {\sphereZ{\longitude}{\latitude}}
    ,remember=\tdplotresx as \lastx (initially \lastix)
    ,remember=\tdplotresy as \lasty (initially \lastiy) 
    ,remember=\tdplotresz as \lastz (initially \lastiz) 
    ] in {30,60,...,360}{

        % rotation transformation for intermediate points
        \tdplottransformrotmain{\Vx}{\Vy}{\Vz}

        % calculate dot product
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentDotProduct}
        {\lastx*\CameraX + \lasty*\CameraY + \lastz*\CameraZ}
    
        % Check if the dot product is positive
        \pgfmathparse{\currentDotProduct>0}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \draw[ultra thin] (\lastx,\lasty,\lastz) -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz);
        \fi
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



One idea that comes to mind would be to draw the whole circles, and use a conditional to calculate if those circles intersect the outer circle. If so, then we could draw the side that faces us. if not, just draw the whole circle if it is on our side (with the question's conditional)

They need to be drawn point-wise so we can calculate the dot product... This slows things down though with the calculations. It would be faster to draw a circle in the xy plane and translate/rotate it into position. But how then would we know if it faces us? (i guess we could use the coordinate components of its midpoint). This seems  like a good approach actually, let me try some things.

Maybe you can try with this nice drawing on TeXample.net from Tomas M. Trzeciak.

@jlab That is a cool drawing! It will take me some time to study the code, but it looks like it is on the right track.

Maybe this can be drawn directly with \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot from the  tikz-3dplot package. Its syntax:
\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[<fill color style>]{<theta steps>}{<phi steps>}%
{<function>}{<line color>}{<fill color>}{<x axis>}{<y axis>}{<z axis>}

Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

% azimuth and elevation
\pgfmathsetmacro{\elevation}{60}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\azimuth}{130}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{90-\elevation}{\azimuth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \pgfsetlinewidth{.2pt}
  \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot{32}{16}%
  {1}{black}{white}{}{}{}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Thank you for pointing this out. One of the features of my question is that the sphere is not aligned with the z-axis (because I used \tdplotsetrotatedcoords and \tdplottransformrotmain). Is there a way to, say, have the north pole of your sphere oriented differently, while still maintaining the projection property?  Apologies before hand if the answer is basic, I will read up on the definition  of \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot to see.

Since a detailed study of the code at TeXample will take some time, as will studying the tikz-3dplot definition for spherical surface, I will accept this answer for reasons ofnot being able to provide an informed follow-up inthe short-term. A follow-up would be better done in a new question, in my opinion.

@Jasper I didn't managed to turn the north pole. With tdplot_main_coords, the azimuth gives a rotation around the rotated z axis (no change for a sphere). With tdplot_rotated_coords the drawing is deformed. Maybe you could report this as a bug in tikz-3dplot.

I suspect that in order to draw surfaces in spherical coordinates (where the z axis isnot upright), we will need more than what tikz-3dplot offers. For instance, they should be little triangles and not rectangles, because four points maybe non-coplannar. When I have time  I will implement such a software, it just takes a while to do it right (I've made similar software before)
